# Is it possible to pass additional data to error view from attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass additional data from my error handler attribute to error view.

This is how I use my attribute:

```
[ErrorHandler (View = "Error", Title = "Some title", Text = "Some text")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, string type, DBRepository repository){...}
```

This is how I pass data:

```
public class ErrorHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    /*Some other stuff*/

    filterContext.Controller.TempData["CustomErrorTitle"] = Title;
    filterContext.Controller.TempData["CustomErrorText"] = Text;
}
```

And this is my error view:

```
@model HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = TempData["CustomErrorTitle"];
}
<h1 class="text-danger">@TempData["CustomErrorTitle"]</h1>
<h1 class="text-danger">@TempData["CustomErrorText"]</h1>
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <div>
        Exception details: @Model.Exception
    </div>
}
```

My code works, but i don't want to use TempData.
Is there other way to pass data without using TempData?

Comment: You've written `div` into what?

Comment: It is exception details visible only for Admins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there's another way using json like this
in you controller

```
return Json(new
{
      CustomErrorTitle= Title ,
      CustomErrorText= Text 
});
```

and in your aspx when you call the action write

```
error:function(data)
{
// you can call your error attribute like this
//data.CustomErrorTitle or data.CustomErrorText
//and do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Feras, but I can't modify all controllers according to your solution. And even if controllers method will finish correct without exception, I pass "extra data", which are title and text

Comment: @RenatZamaletdinov you can use if-else statement to avoid returning the extra data if the method will finish correct